# unordered_map Vs map Vs array - Memory analysis

Tags: c++, std

As the title says, I would want to know the memory differences between `unordered_map`, `map`, and `array`.

Example:

```
unordered_map <long long , int> a;
map <long long , int> b;
long long c[1000000];
```

`a` and `b` have 1000000 stored elements.

I want to keep it as simple as possible. I searched on the internet and I didn't find a proper answer. I found that `map` and `unordered_map` use more memory than an `array`, but I don't know how to approach it.

EDIT: How to approach the memory differences, like if I store exact the same 2 elements, what are the memory differences.

Comment: "*I don't know how to approach it.*" How to approach what, exactly?

Comment: how much memory map and unordered_map use is an implementation detail. If you want it in terms of big O notation then they are all equivalent.

Comment: You could implement a custom [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). It is specified as template argument, e.g. `std::vector<int, custom_allocator>`.

Comment: `c` is of course expected to be the smallest, if only because it stores half the data. It stores 1000000 instances of `long long`, while `a` and `b` store that plus 1000000 instances of `int`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, but I know what elements are stored and they are the same.

Comment: As your objective is to store 1000000 elements for a,b, and c, you can make array c as type int only, and accessing of element using key is slower in b compared to rest.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++11 the standard library containers support stateful allocators: you can pass an allocator type which records the amount of data allocated and track the maximum use. You’ll need to also account for the object size as for an array there isn’t really an allocator as the array is a built-in entity.

[Here](https://ideone.com/Ymb36c) is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static constexpr long total_size = 1000000;

template<typename T>
class CountingAllocator
{
public:
    shared_ptr<size_t> d_max = make_shared<size_t>(0u);
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;

    CountingAllocator() = default;
    template <typename S>
    CountingAllocator(CountingAllocator<S> const& other): d_max(other.d_max) {}
    size_t size() const { return *d_max; }
    T* allocate(size_t size) {
        size *= sizeof(T);
        *d_max += size;
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(operator new(size));
    }
    void deallocate(void* ptr, size_t) {
        operator delete(ptr);
    }
    friend bool operator== (CountingAllocator const& c0, CountingAllocator const& c1) {
        return c0.d_max == c1.d_max;
    } 

    friend bool operator!= (CountingAllocator const& c0, CountingAllocator const& c1) {
        return !(c0 == c1);
    }
};

template <typename T>
void size(char const* name) {
    CountingAllocator<typename T::value_type> allocator;
    T m(allocator);
    for (int i = 0; i != total_size; ++i) {
        m[i] = i;
    }
    cout << name << "="  << allocator.size() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    size<map<long, long long, less<int>, CountingAllocator<pair<long const, long long>>>>("map");
    size<unordered_map<long, long long, hash<long>, equal_to<long>, CountingAllocator<pair<long const, long long>>>>("unordered_map");
    cout << "array=" << sizeof(long long[total_size]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With clang on ideone this prints (I aligned the sizes here, though):

```
map=          48000000
unordered_map=40654880
array=         8000000
```

The array has, of course, the smallest footprint (zero per element overhead). I’m surprised that the average per element overhead is smaller for `unordered_map` than for `map`. Using 5 words in addition to the data seems a bit excessive.

Comment: This analysis is probably underestimating the real memory consumption for maps in many cases. The underlying memory manager will probably return 32 or 64 byte aligned addresses for pointers allocated via new-operator, thus a node in the map will cost not 40/48 bytes but 64.

Comment: @ead: Yes, this analysis only computes what the data structures actually ask for. Any additional maintenance will be in top of that. Of course, with a suitable allocator the overhead can be reduced, e.g., by maintaining a pool of buffers matching exactly the size requested.